# How come this code prints "yes" even though there is an assignment and not comparison operator in the following code

Tags: c

There is an assignment operator in the if condition and when executed it prints "yes" as output. I didn't get it.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float f = 0.1;

    if (f=0.1)
    {
        printf("Yes");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf ("no");
    }
}
```

Comment: The value of an assignment expression is the new value of whatever was on the left side of the assignment operator.  In this case, that's `0.1`, which is nonzero, and therefore counts as true for `if`.  Compare what happens if you change the `0.1` on the right side of the assignment to `0.2` and to `0.0`.

Comment: Because the result of the assignment is interpreted as a boolean value. `==0` means `false`, `!=0` means `true`

Comment: regarding: `float f = 0.1;`   The literal: `0.1`  is a `double`, not a `float`   The correct way to write the literal is to include a trailing `f` in the literal.  I.E.  `float f = 0.1f;`

Comment: regarding: `if (f=0.1)`  This will always result in `true`.   The statement should be: `if (f == 0.1f )`  However, not all fractions can be exactly represented in  in `float`, so this equality may or maynot be `true`  However, the assignment (of anything other than 0.0f) will be resolved to `true`

Comment: @zwol Thanks, I got it. When we insert 0.0 instead of 0.1 the statement evaluates to false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assignment operator has a result, it is the variable that just has been assigned!

So the code actually is equivalent to:

```
f = 0.1;
if(f) // and as unequal to 0...
```

You can try to assign 0.0 for comparison:

```
if(f = 0.0)
```

Now it will print `no`.

Comment: and this syntax feature has lead to "yoda-style" checks like if(0==var) instead of more naturally looking if(var==0), which with a typo can become if(var=0)...